# Scale markers in external Tikz file

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, matlab2tikz

I use external .tikz files to include graphics in my LaTeX document. These .tikz files are generated by [matlab2tikz](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22022). 
The scatter plots that come out though have very small markers. I want to scale these markers. Right now I include the .tikz file as follows:

```
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \newlength\figureheight 
    \newlength\figurewidth 
    \setlength\figureheight{0.5\linewidth} 
    \setlength\figurewidth{0.5\linewidth}
    \input{images/filename.tikz}
    \caption{caption}
    \label{fig:label}
\end{figure}
```

How do I scale the markers at the moment I `\input` the .tikz file. I don't want to edit the  content of the .tikz file itself.
A method to scale plot markers globally would also be acceptable.

Comment: Try `\tikzset{mark size=5}` (or some other value) before the `\input` statement. If that doesn't work, please edit your question to include the code in `filename.tikz`.

Comment: I don't know how matlab2tikz handles the plots but you can try adding `\tikzset{every mark/.append style={scale=3}}` in the preamble.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can specify the marker size globally by putting

```
\tikzset{mark size=5}
```

(or some other value) somewhere before your `tikzpicture`.

Comment: what if I actually want to scale the marker sizes, not just set them all to a single size, i.e., I have multiple marker sizes and what the relative sizes between markers to remain the same, I just want to scale everything...