# Change axis number format for external tikz file

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, formatting

I'm using `\input{filename.tikz}` to include .tikz graphs created by [matlab2tikz](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22022) in my LaTeX document. As shown in a comment on [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/106549/scale-markers-in-external-tikz-file) it is possible to change the plot marker size when the document is inputted, without altering the original .tikz file.

Now I'm looking for a way to change the axis number formatting in the same fashion.
I have numbers on the y-axis that are of the form `5 x 10^-2` where I want them just to be `0.05`.

I understand from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/54356/13134) that this has more to do with pgfplot than with tikz, but I'm not sure how I would use the command given in the answer right before my `\input` statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The keys given in the `axis` options can also be set outside the `axis` environment by using

```
\pgfplotsset{
    every x tick label/.append style  =
        { 
          /pgf/number format/.cd,
           precision = 0, 
           fixed
        }
}
```

or, equivalently

```
\pgfkeys{
    /pgfplots/every x tick label/.append style  =
        { 
          /pgf/number format/.cd,
           precision = 0, 
           fixed
        }
}
```

For the example given in the answer this would become:

```
\pgfkeys{
        /pgfplots/every y tick label/.append style  =
            { 
              /pgf/number format/.cd,
               precision = 2, 
               fixed
            }
    }
```