# How to set Tikz scatter marker weight?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, plot

I'm using tikz to produce scatter plots as shown in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/106549/scale-markers-in-external-tikz-file).
I can define the marker size with `\tikzset{mark size=8}` but now I'm looking for a way to make the line of the marker thicker in a similar way.
Is this possible with `\tikzset`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can set the size of the line width for the markers using `\tikzset{mark options={line width=3pt}}`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{mark options={mark size=5, line width=3pt}}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot [only marks, fill=red] {rnd};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```